# How to use an Apache load balancer with Bokeh, with HTTP and WS protocols?

Tags: apache, http, websocket, bokeh

I'm trying to get Apache to work with more than one Bokeh server. Everything works fine with one server behind a reverse-proxy, but when I try configuring a load balancer, I keep getting an internal server error. I know there is some information about load balancing in the Bokeh docs, but it's only explained for Nginx, and I'm having a hard time linking the dots.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the websocket protocol. I've read a bit about this, and I've seen examples for simple HTTP load balancers, but not for WS and HTTP load balancers.

Do I have to create 2 clusters, one for HTTP and one for WS? How can I work with WS and HTTP wihtin a load balancer?

I have included what I have for now in my Apache config. Please note that I have only one server per cluster for testing purposes.

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    # Server 1
    BalancerMember http://localhost:5100/foo
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://mycluster/ws>
    # Server 1
    BalancerMember ws://localhost:5100/foo/ws
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access.log" combined
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.log"

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Location /foo>
        ProxyPass         balancer://mycluster
        ProxyPassReverse  balancer://mycluster
    </Location>

    <Location /foo/ws>
        ProxyPass         balancer://mycluster/ws
        ProxyPassReverse  balancer://mycluster/ws
    </Location>

    Alias /static /var/www/static
    <Directory /var/www/static>
        # directives to effect the static directory
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Don't you need your Alias created to /foo/static instead of just /static? And I assume you have copy to /var/www/static what's in lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/static right? Even though you say Everything works fine with one server. So I guess your static configuration should be fine. About the balancer. I hope to learn here too how to make it work.

Comment: Maybe there are more than one way of configuring this, but the code I pasted is working, so just /static is okay too I guess. And yes, I copied the static directory from .../bokeh/server.

Comment: In the end, did you make it work? The Bokeh docs still lacks information on load balancing with Apache.